# new string of string in code 

Tags: c#

in C++ it's

```
string x = "hello \
Hello";
```

it's \

in C# I really don't know :) but \ doesn't works and I can't find information. That's annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string x = @"Hello
world";
```

Answer (score 4):

Prefix your string with the @ symbol so that the newline character is included in the string.

```
string x = @"hello 
Hello";
```